# I am finding difficult to do assertion on the below API response

Tags: postman, postman-pre-request-script, postman-testcase

```json
[{
    "FP": "DAV1",
    "SMO": false,
    "SP": [{
        "name": "FOP1",
        "Exam": [{
            "Marksguid": "a02dac4f-630f-4ed0-aa54-8c7044b71f2f",
            "apiUrl": "test1",
            "interval": 65,
            "schemaVersion": "1.2",
            "authenticationType": "Basic"
        }]
    }]
}, {
    "FP": "FOP10",
    "SMO": false,
    "SP": [{
        "name": "FOP10",
        "Exam": [{
            "Marksguid": "f778dd51-d401-42ca-a5ea-4920db5708b2",
            "apiUrl": "test1",
            "interval": 65,
            "schemaVersion": "1.2",
            "authenticationType": "Basic"
        }]
    }]
}, {
    "FP": "FOP2",
    "SMO": false,
    "SP": [{
        "name": "FOP2",
        "Exam": [{
            "Marksguid": "8c49f158-7286-4f15-904c-564b41966b6b",
            "apiUrl": "test1",
            "interval": 65,
            "schemaVersion": "1.2",
            "authenticationType": "Basic"
        }]
    }]
}, {
    "FP": "FOP3",
    "SMO": false,
    "SP": [{
        "name": "FOP3",
        "Exam": [{
            "Marksguid": "c5f2893f-b8fb-4494-8126-b3de47ebe440",
            "apiUrl": "test1",
            "interval": 65,
            "schemaVersion": "1.2",
            "authenticationType": "Basic"
        }]
    }]
}]
```

I want to do assertion for "FP": "FOP2", and the underneath name and exam all those stuff. Could someone help me on this.

Answer (score 0):

First of all, you parse the response body:

```js
const responseJson = pm.response.json();
```

then you can access the data via `responseJson` variable.

There's an array, and you're interested in `FP` properties, so you can get only those:

```js
const fps = responseJson.map(arr => arr.FP);
```

finally you can assert there's `FOP2` present:

```js
pm.expect(fps).to.include.members(["FOP2"]);
```

So the whole check could look like this:

```js
pm.test("Array contains 'FOP2'", () => {
  const responseJson = pm.response.json();
  const fps = responseJson.map(arr => arr.FP);

  pm.expect(fps).to.include.members(["FOP2"]);
});
```

---

> and the underneath name and exam all those stuff

I don't exactly know what you want to assert there, you'd need to be more specific. But perhaps you can continue on your own after my example.

Comment: Thank you!! I'm getting error like this Array contains 'FOP2' | AssertionError: expected [ Array(42) ] to have the same members as [ 'FOP2' ]

Comment: I've used the same thing you have give pm.test("Array contains 'FOP2'", () => {
  const responseJson = pm.response.json();
  const fps = responseJson.map(arr => arr.FP);

  pm.expect(fps).to.have.members(["FOP2"]);
});

Comment: "FP": "FOP2",
    "SMO": false,
    "SP": [{
        "name": "FOP2",
        "Exam": [{
            "Marksguid": "8c49f158-7286-4f15-904c-564b41966b6b",
            "apiUrl": "test1",
            "interval": 65,
            "schemaVersion": "1.2",
            "authenticationType": "Basic"
        }]
    }] Also when I "FP": "FOP2", I need to assert "SMO": false, and following parameter aswell  "SP": [{
        "name": "FOP2",
        "Exam": [{
            "Marksguid": "8c49f158-7286-4f15-904c-564b41966b6b",

Comment: My Question:

1. I want to assert “FP”: “FOP2”.
2. And If 1st step is success. I want to Assert “SMO”: false,
3. And also I need to Assert SP.name.FOP2 and its corresponding Exam.“Marksguid”:

Comment: @dhiwakaranarumugam: there is one change in my post now, it should be `pm.expect(fps).to.include.members(["FOP2"]);`, because `fps` is a superset of the expected array. that's why you got the error. more on thet in docs https://www.chaijs.com/api/bdd/#method_members

Comment: Thank you so much it works well. I have another question. Is there a way to MYSQL database and select (get) a row of data from the table and can we use it in a Postman..

Comment: This works very well